# Flattening a list of strings and lists to work on each item

Tags: python, arrays

I am currently working with different input types -

My input could either look like this:

```
 [term1, term2, term3,...]
```

or

```
[[term1, term2], term3]
```

or

```
[[term1, term2], [term3, term4]]
```

I would like to find a way to flatten it to a format over which I could loop in order to use the terms.

My code at the moment looks like this:

```
for entry in initial_list:
    if type(entry) is str:
       do_something(entry)
    elif type(entry) is list:
       for term in entry:
          do_something(term)
```

The goal would be to perform the flattening in a more Pythonic way, using list comprehension or mapping, instead of explicit for loops.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki - That only works if every element of the list is another list. OP has mentioned that some of their items are strings.

Comment: @Sembei Norimaki, Not quite. The answers there assume a uniform list of lists.

Comment: @ikegami in the linked question they propose using  `merged = list(itertools.chain(*myList))` which works for me in the three cases the OP requested

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki in the case of 3 strings in the list, the method you mention splits them on a character by character basis

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flatten an irregular list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists)

Comment: This post is being discussed [on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418099/opinionated-question-for-performance-and-readability-improvements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more concise approach is:

```py
for entry in initial_list:
    for term in ([entry] if isinstance(entry, str) else entry):
        do_something(term)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're very close. It might however be better to use `isinstance`. Try:

```
result = list()
for entry in initial_list:
    if isinstance(entry, str):
        result.append(entry)
    elif isinstance(entry, list):
        for term in entry:
            result.append(term)
```